# What is meaning the "wound" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I don't know what is meaning the "wound" in the sentence.

> Three men dressed for business travel in jeans and dress shirts loaded backpacks into the trunk of a black coupe and **wound** their way through the center of a major European city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Wound` is being used here as a synonym for `wandered` or `roamed`.

`Wound` is the past-tense of `wind` (pronounced with a hard "i" sound, like "kind"), where someone who is `winding` is walking back-and-forth.

So, if someone "wound up somewhere", then they walked back-and-forth, definitely not directly, and eventually arrived at the destination.

Answer (score 0):

"Wound" could be the past and past participle of the word "wind". To move along a twisting path or route.